# list to bytes conversion on python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, byte

I have a list with the following values:

```
l = [205, 1, 239, 215, 48]
when I convert it with bytes by doing 
byte_l = bytes(l)
print(byte_l)
```

gives:
b'\xcd\x01\xef\xd70'

but I want it to return
b'\xcd\x01\xef\xd7\x30'

when i do

```
byte_l == b'\xCD\x01\xEF\xD7\x30'
```

it returns True

What is going on here?
And how do I get it to return what I want it to?

Comment: `'\x30'` is the same as `'0'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the ASCII representation of the bytes the `print` can interpret. Your last number is `48`, whose utf representation is `0`. Try this:

```py
x = bytearray(b'\x30')
print(x)
```

You get:

```sh
bytearray(b'0')
```

If you look at the last character of your print, just after `\xd7` (i.e., 215) there is `0`, that is the representation of 48 (30 in hexadecimal) in [ASCII code](https://www.ascii-code.com/).

If you try with this code:

```py
l = [47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52]
byte_l = bytes(l)
print(byte_l)
```

this is what you get:

```sh
b'/01234'
```

All bytes were interpreted as ASCII codes.

If you want to print the content of the bytes bypassing the ASCII interpretation, you can use something like this:

```py
print(''.join(['\\x{:02x}'.format(x) for x in byte_l]))
```

If `byte_l = bytes([47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52])` it gives:

```sh
\x2f\x30\x31\x32\x33\x34
```

while in your case (`byte_l = bytes([205, 1, 239, 215, 48])`), it prints:

```sh
\xcd\x01\xef\xd7\x30
```

Comment: I understand, I figured it had to do something with the different representation. Is there any way to change this? I do know that doing "1234".encode() will get you b"1234", would it be prudent to then take the b'\xCD\x01\xEF\xD7\x30'.decode()? but I do know that cd cannot be properly decoded so I'm not sure what to do with that. Since b"1234".decode() would work

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your comment, BTW, I've updated the answer suggesting a way to print bytes avoiding ASCII interpretation.

Comment: @MccauleyPeters Python picks the simplest representation of a character always.  It reserves the `\x` form for bytes outside the ASCII range that would be unprintable or have inconsistent encoding.